# Win32 edit control EM_SETSEL doesn't work

Tags: c, winapi

I have a button and a single-line edit control with some default text, and I want to highlight all the edit control's text when the button is clicked.

For some reason, SendMessage has no effect and the text isn't highlighted - what am I doing wrong?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)
{
    case WM_CREATE:                                     
        hwndEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("edit"), L"Default text",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
            10, 10, 150, 24, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_EDIT,
            hInst, NULL);

        hwndButton = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("button"), L"Mark text",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            100, 100, 75, 24, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON,
            hInst, NULL);
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:                                    
        {
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDC_BUTTON:
                    SendMessage(hwndEdit, EM_SETSEL, 0, -1);
                    break;

                case IDM_ABOUT:
                    DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                    break;
                case IDM_EXIT:
                    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                    break;
                default:
                    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:                                      
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!
Chris

Comment: Are you sure the ``case IDC_BUTTON`` is getting hit?

Comment: Yes, IDC_BUTTON is getting hit and the edit control receives EM_SETSEL (checked with Spy++).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the `ES_NOHIDESEL` style?

> Negates the default behavior for an edit control. The default behavior hides the selection when the control loses the input focus and inverts the selection when the control receives the input focus. If you specify ES_NOHIDESEL, the selected text is inverted, even if the control does not have the focus.

Comment: That was it. IMO it would have been more intuitive if this was the default behaviour of an edit control, but I guess they had different worries back then.